# Does Salesforce Marketing cloud support .gz compressed files

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-import

I have just been asked if .gz can be unzipped in marketing Cloud?

I can't find a list of supported compressed files in the help docs

Comment: By default, file transfers only handle zip files. I'd raise a case with SFMC Support. They have a Data Extract type that allows compression/extraction of Gzip files as part of your Automations that can be provisioned to the account.

Comment: Do you know if SFMC can unzip .gz files or is zip a default settings as well?

Comment: Default is zip for file transfers, but you can handle Gzip(.gz) files using the Custom Extracts I mentioned.

Comment: here are the file formats supported by MC `https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_supported_file_types_portfolio.htm&type=5`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Marketing Cloud supports .gz (Gzip) compressed file.
[image]